# "Like" button for a database in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, formula, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Is there a way to implement a "Like" button for a database in Lotus Notes. I basically want to have a document in Notes, where is will be possible to click a button and its then liked.

At the moment I have a button but it can be pressed as many times as they want. If possible I would like to be able to only click it once?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of counting the "likes", or incrementing a counter each time the button is pressed, instead save the current user's name to a list and then count the number of users in that list to tell you the number of likes.

On click this would be roughly:

```
ListOfLikes := @Unique(ListOfLikes:@UserName);
```

And then to display the count:

```
@Count(ListOfLikes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Ken's answer, you could use a pair of buttons for "Like" and "Unlike" with hide-when formulas.  For the paragraph containing the Like button

```
 !(@Username = ListOfLikes);
```

For the paragraph containing the Unlike button

```
@Username = ListOfLikes
```

(You don't need to use @IsMember for this, as comparing a scalar string against a list works the same way.)

The formula for the actual Unlike button would have to remove a name from the list, like this:

```
@Trim(@Replace(ListOfLikes;@Username;""));
```